# How to create simple post/get API making simple calling to GAE database using Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to create simple post/get API making simple calling to GAE database using Google App Engine? Like create DB item retrive and delete. How to acsess it after you created it?

Comment: Probably you could start with the tutorial: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Java as the language on the app engine. You will have to make a RESTful application using servlets which defines certain CRUD functionalities. Make servlets for create, update, delete and select/query.

for example:

http://app.appspot.com/create?name=tablename

http://app.appspot.com/query?table=tablename&id=200

The create servlet will have to create a new Model on the datastore. The query servlet will take in an ID and return back the row. Might I also suggest using JSON as the dataformat for receiving data at the client side.